# Default email address for managing access requests

Tags: 2010, permissions, site

When creating a new site, does the (default) email address for managing the access requests belong to the person who created the site? I am the one receiving the notifications on the parent site. Someone else (another admin) created a subsite and he was receiving the emails for access request until I changed the address to mine.

Is that what is happening or is there some other way in which the recipient of access requests is determined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any site i.e. parent site or a subsite (that is not inheriting permissions from its parent).. Go to Site Actions -> Site Permissions -> In the ribbon find "Manage Access Requests"

This is the email address being used to forward the access requests, you can change it to yours. By default, the owner/creator of the site is taken.